# Learning of the same keras ML model is differ after rerun on colab.research.google com

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I started `model.fit` and it showed me excellent convergence. But after that, I ran it again and it doesn't want to learn. I didn't change the code, just rerun, but I had no convergence at all. After researches in all day I found out that if I make factory reset runtime and then restart Chrome, the model learns well. But the second time leads to crash again. The factory reset only does not help.
If I've started another model before this, I get the same bad result, if I did not restart Chrome.
I feed it `tf.dataset` and use pretty exotic `TimeDistributed` layer, but seems to me it is no reason of

The first run on clear chrome:

[image: good learning]

The second run. I change nothing at all, just run again:

[image: bad learning]

What does this mean? and how can I fix this?

Comment: That's very strange. Do you get the same behavior in a different browser like Firefox?

Comment: When I opened Google colaboratory  in MS Edge it warned me:
"This site may not work in your browser. Please use a supported browser"
When I try open my Jupiter Notebook it said:
"There was an error loading this notebook. Ensure that the file is accessible and try again.
'TextDecoder' is not defined"

This service works well in Chrome always, so I think my trouble is not because of Chrome.